# Invalid value for property 'FilePath'

Tags: 2013-sp1

I'd like to include "-" in my published directories.
I updated the **cm_xml_usr.xsd** file:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="Directory">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
        <xsd:pattern value="[-a-zA-Z0-9!\(\)_\-~.]*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="FilePath">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Simple type used to restrict file paths</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="256"/>
        <xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9!\(\)_\-~.\\]+"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

But after restarting COM, IIS, Service Host etc I can't seem to get the change picked up - I always get

> "Invalid value for property 'FilePath'."

I'm clearly missing something!

Comment: Can you try it like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589074/regex-should-hyphens-be-escaped

Answer (score 2):

Because the `-` character is used to define ranges in character classes in regular expressions, if you want to use it literally, then you put it at the beginning or the end. So `[a-z]` will not match a `-`, but `[-a-z]` will. If I remember correctly, other kinds of escaping won't work in a character class.

`<xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9!\(\)_\-~.\\]+"/>` will match any characters in the `a` to `z` range, upper or lower case, and also any characters in the range between `\` and `~`, so it won't match a `'-'`.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern for `Directory` has `-` *twice*, which is probably why you're not able to save.

`<xsd:pattern value="[-a-zA-Z0-9!\(\)_\-~.]*"/>`

Try removing the first hyphen before the `a` or the escaped `\-`. Your `Filepath` pattern looks right.

Community member, Robert Jin posted a [similar example on his blog](http://rjin-tridion.blogspot.com/2013/01/allowing-in-tridion-publication-path.html). I also found a useful tool to test regular expressions: http://www.regexr.com/. :-)

Comment: Thanks Alvin. Is there anymore I need to do other than restarting everything to get Tridion to accept the update?

Comment: For 2011, I believe it was just COM+. If restarting everything didn't work, maybe try deleting browser cache?